# Image Loading seems to slow down Javascript execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, image

I am working on a straightforward web app, purely Javascript.

One of the core functionalities is loading and viewing images.

When a lot of big images are loaded, the script execution often slows down or even halts until some of them are done loading, this is especially noticeable with large `.gif`s (HTML5 video is not as bad for some reason).

The images are loaded by setting the `background-image` css attribute of divs with jQuerys `.css()`, there are no sort of blocking events or sleep / wait time until images are loaded.

Weirdly, on OSX, scrolling (with the Macbook trackpad) temporarily relieves the halt / slowdown, even while in fullscreen (OSX browsers leave wiggle room for the trackpad), which makes me think that it's a problem of rendering or resource allocation of some sort. It feels like the browser does not have the need to redraw, and is only forced to do so because of the scrolling.

I'd like to force it to redraw constantly, 60 FPS.

Comment: So are you constantly setting the background-image property on scroll, even on images that already have this set? Maybe you should look into lazy-loading ?

Comment: @adeneo Not on scroll, it goes: User Input -> Load ca. 20 images -> Manipulate DOM depending on further user input (slideshow etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the loading of **lot of big images** and showing them in the application.
You can try for Image lazy loading concept where images are loaded/fetched as soon as you scroll the window.

May be this [link](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage) would be helpful. This plugin will take care of loading images when user scrolls and its very easy to use.

Someone can try the concept of [WebWorker](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_workers.htm). Its multithreading in javascript.

Comment: I thought about this as well, but im still curious: Why does this slow down rendering if the browser actually still has resources to render?

Comment: When a browser deals with many images it takes time to render. Its not only about resources, its about fetching the images and then rendering into the UI. Consider an example of facebook, sometimes even though page is rendered, images take time to show. Moreover, browser uses single thread per tab(this depends upon the browser), so it affects the performance. May be you can look for some work turn around using newer concept called WebWorker.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, to not forget image optimization.

Comment: Sadly out of the question because the images don't come from me (Hotlinks to wherever, it depends on user input).

Comment: I guess this time is not possible.